# Error 401 'INVALID_KEY_TYPE' with FireBase and c#

Tags: c#

I am implementing c # with FireBase, it sends me error 401 'INVALID_KEY_TYPE'

```
private static Uri FireBasePushNotificationsURL = new Uri("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        private static string ServerKey = "AIzaSyA9fL8lPyxcrngIDDsDeUbq9sPTkavXXXX";

public static async Task<bool> SendPushNotification(string deviceTokens, string title, string body, object data)
{
    bool sent = false;

    if (deviceTokens.Count() > 0)
    {
        //Object creation

        var messageInformation = new 
        {
            to = "fZ0EyxU-tsk:APA91bE3-qo4DwL9phteDJC8pG6iLdr-YSSl-N_2SJne3U6eyUhmEuZNQhJi0YM-XXXXXX",
            priority = "high",
            content_available = true,
            notification = new
            {
                body = "Test",
                title = "Test miguel",
                badge = 1
            },
        };

        //Object to JSON STRUCTURE => using Newtonsoft.Json;
        string jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageInformation);

        //Create request to Firebase API
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, FireBasePushNotificationsURL);

        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "key=" + ServerKey);
        request.Content = new StringContent(jsonMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage result;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            result = await client.SendAsync(request);
            sent = sent && result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
    }

    return sent;

}
```

Comment: It's a little unclear on what exactly youre asking. Are you questioning if you keys are in a valid format? Are you questioning why Firebase would be rejecting valid keys?

Also please do be careful about posting question with keys, even if partially obfuscated, as this could be sensitive information.

Answer (score 62):

I have the same problem. The problem is that you take the wrong server key.
The right firebase server key is `Project > Settings > Cloud Messaging > Server Key`